# Single occurrences in int [] Array

Tags: java

I want that the amount of occurrences of single numbers is getting printed out. But the problem is that just the number that is defined by count is getting printed out.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = {10,11,9,5,5,3,2,2,1};
    int nt = countSingles(numbers);
    System.out.println(nt);
}

public static int countSingles(int[]numbers) {
    if(numbers == null)return -1;
    if(numbers.length<=0)return -1;
    int count =1;
    for(int i=0; i<numbers.length-1;i++) {
        if(numbers[i]<numbers[i++])return -1;
        if(numbers[i]>numbers[i++]&&numbers[i++]>numbers[i+2]) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: You should consider going back to basics here. How would you solve this with a pen and paper? What you are doing right now makes no sense, as you seem to compare greater/less than against future numbers. This is not even close to what you are trying to do.

Comment: I think you are confusing `i++` and `i+1`. Not that you want to use either, really, but I think you *really* don't mean `i++`.

Comment: careful using `i++` like this... you are actuall checking on the same iteration `i` with `i+1` then `i+1` and `i+2` and `i+3`with `i+4` (if my head count is correct). `i++` change the value of the variable, not like `i+1`.

Comment: thought I could just take the next number of the array.

Comment: Ok thx then I will try it another way

Comment: I don't think your answer is **that** incorrect, it's just not the way people would usually solve this. Read about what `i++` actually does and remember that arrays are not sorted by default. You will maybe run into other smaller issues after that, but trying to get your own solution to work will probably help you more than just copying a solution (still +1 to [OptimusCrime](https://stackoverflow.com/users/921563/optimuscrime)). Especially if your are still learning the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a very basic approach. There are MANY ways of doing this. My approach was meant to be easy to understand and follow.

```
int[] numbers = {10,11,9,5,5,3,2,2,1};

public static int countSingles(int[] numbers) {
    // Avoid NPE
    if (numbers == null) {
        return -1;
    }

    int count = 0;

    // Loop the numbers once
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        // Loop the numbers one more time, comparing each of them 
        // all the other numbers in the array
        for (int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {

            // Do not compare the same number to itself, as these 
            // will always be equal (and is not really what we want to do)
            if (i == j) {
                continue;
            }

            // If the two numbers are equal, continue to the next number, 
            // this one is not a single occurence
            if (numbers[i] == numbers[j]) {
                break;
            }

            // If the value (index) of j equals the length of the array, 
            // and we did not break on the previous if, we know
            // that the current (outer) number is a single occurence, 
            // increase the count
            if (j == (numbers.length - 1)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    // Return the number of single occurences
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use java 8 and stream and **FILTER** :

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] numbers = {10,11,9,5,5,3,2,2,1};
        Long nt = countSingles(numbers);
        System.out.println(nt);

    }

    public static Long countSingles(Integer[]numbers) {
        List<Integer> list =  Arrays.asList(numbers);        
        return  list.stream().filter(i->isSingle(i,list)).count();
    }

    static boolean isSingle(int i, List<Integer> list ){
        int occurence=0;
            for (Integer aInteger:list) {
                if(aInteger==i){
                    occurence++;
                    if(occurence>1){
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I think this could be simplified by using `list.stream().filter(...).count()`

Comment: Also you could use `list.filter(entry -> entry == i).count() < 1` in your `isSingle` method and use `Arrays.stream(numbers)` instead of creating the temporary list

Comment: your second solution is great also , but i created a temporary list to simplify my code

Answer (score 0):

You  can try the below code: It works too, i guess quite efficient as we will be using HashMap

```
import java.util.HashMap;


public class arrayTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = {10,11,9,5,5,3,2,2,1};
        System.out.println(countSingles(numbers));

    }

public static HashMap<Integer, Integer> countSingles(int[]numbers) {

HashMap<Integer, Integer> hash = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

for(int i=0; i<numbers.length-1;i++) {
    if(hash.get(numbers[i])!= null){
       int num = hash.get(numbers[i]);
       num++;
       hash.put(numbers[i], num);
    }else{
        hash.put(numbers[i], 1);
    }
}

return hash;
}
}
```

Comment: But now `countSingles` does not return an integer but a `HashMap`. Could you also check the formatting of your code?

Comment: @MarkusK, yes, my code returns a HashMap which will have the count of each integer and it occurrences. I thought returning a hashMap would be better rather than an int. Also, i did format my code. Please let me know if I am missing something

Answer (score 0):

The appearance of each number should be counted and stored. i.e. in Map

```
   int[] numbers = {10, 11, 9, 5, 5, 3, 2, 2, 1};

    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = Arrays.stream(numbers)
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), mapping(identity(), toList())));
```

Then it will be possible to find single numbers.

```
  long nt = map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue().size() == 1).count();
```